# Your first application after "Hello World"

Tags: programming-languages

I understand it is kind of bloated question, but.... learning new language, you first write "Hello world", right? :) And what is your next application?

What kind of application would walk you through basics? I read some programming books and usually authors show you the programming language basics and features by writinig some application. It is easy in the beggining but then they add more and more features and all in all it is already a very featured application in the end of the book. I want to know what application after "Hello, world" is the best for practicing and discovering the language you are learning.

It might be something like: get all questions from first page of stackoverflow and create files named by questions titles and create directories names with uppercased first letter of each question and then put your text files in the corresponding directories. After all, count all files in all directories and tell how many files and directories was created and list how many files there are in each directory.

Comment: This isn't really a question. Stack Overflow is for questions that can be answered, not discussed.

Comment: Well, I don't want to discuss it. I want an answer :)

Comment: If you need some idea try searching for "code kata" on google.

Comment: Oh okay. thanks for clarifying. can you remove the 'in your opinion' part of your post? it's rather misleading.

Comment: Without narrowing it down to a specific language this question is far too open-ended to have an answer. Even if it were a single language it would be questionable.

Comment: P.S. Most people don't learn a language for the fun of it, they have a specific goal in mind. Or at least they know the kinds of applications the language are most suited for.

Comment: Ok. Of course, I realise it is not a forum, but it is still a question. I'm looking for opinions and advices. It is interesting what people usually write first. I'm learning `Python` (I write my blog in `Django` now) and `Java` (writing `Android` app). But both of my tasks need some preparation (working w/ directories, files, datatypes, etc.)... That's why I probably should do something less difficult first. That's why I wondering is there some **interesting** task to solve right after "Hello world"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stereotypical 'next exercise' after Hello World is something to teach loops - like printing all the fibonacci numbers [as far as the built in datatypes can handle] or generating the lyrics to 99 bottles of beer on the wall or the 12 days of christmas. Then after that is basic input handling (Incidentally, if you've got a bad C tutorial, this part is most likely to teach you something you will have to unlearn later, whether it's `gets` or `scanf` or `fflush(stdin)`)

Then a bit later you get to the 'application' kind of thing you mentioned i.e. add this feature and add that feature and soon enough you've got a real program.

Comment: I think I'll go with `fibonacci`, `factorial`, `99 bottles of beer on the wall` and playing with stdin/stdout (let the user decide how many bottles of beer does he need :) ).

Comment: Fibonacci and factorial are also ways to teach recursion... including why recursion can be bad when there's not tail call optimization.

Answer (score 2):

That's kinda complex for the "just after hello world" program. The next program usually involves taking some input from the user and then branching logic based on that input.

AKA: Enter a Number and then Multiply by 2.

It gets you used to input, output, and sanitizing the input you receive.

Answer (score 1):

That's always the question, "What should I make/build/create/develop?"

Personally, I always just play with STDIN/STDOUT, understand the conditions, and just play/break whatever I can think of.